# How to make Doctrine lookups like Doctrine_table->find, ->findby* use the query/results cache (doctrine 1.2)

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

For the first time I have set up a results cache in doctrine 1.24 by applying the following code:

```
$servers = array(
  'host'       => 'localhost',
  'port'       => 11211,
  'persistent' => true
);
$cacheDriver = new Doctrine_Cache_Memcache(
  array(
    'servers' => $servers,
    'compression' => false
  )
);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE,$cacheDriver);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE_LIFESPAN, 3600 );
```

This works great for caching DQL quires such as:

```
enter code here$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Software s')
    ->leftJoin('s.Files f')
    ->useResultCache();
$q->execute();
```

However, What interests me is how do I cache table lookups such as:

```
xyzTable::getInstance()->findOneBySufff($stuff);
```

These are by far more frequent in my application code. 
How do I achieve this? 
Additionally, if anyone has a guide for using memcache with doctrine 1.2 I'd be more then happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the

```
xyzTable::getInstance()->findOneBySufff($stuff);
```

functions in your own xyzTable class.

```
class xyzTable extends Doctrine_Table 
{
     public function findOneByStuff($stuff) {
         return $this->createQuery('x')
              ->select('x.*')
              ->where('x.stuff = ?', $stuff)
              ->useResultCache()
              ->fetchOne();

     }
}
```

Make sure you enable Table creation in your 'doctrine-cli' script

```
 ....
 $doctrine_config['generate_models_options'] = 
    array('generateTableClasses' => true);

 $cli = new Doctrine_Cli($doctrine_config);
 ....
```